# How do I submit a new item onto page? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Doing a project for school.  I have to be able to add a grocery item onto a list with the controls "check" and "delete" inside the box with the new item. There is already 4 items on the list for reference. Ive gotten as far as being able to add the box, with the food item inside, but i cant seem to get the buttons inside, along with the same font and style as the others on the list.

[image: Screenshot of what I'm getting when I add item]
**jQuery**

```
function addItem(){
    $('#js-shopping-list-form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const textInput = $('#shopping-list-entry').val();
        $('ul').append('<li>' + textInput + '</li>')
    });
};
$(addItem);
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button, input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#shopping-list-item {
  width: 250px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shopping-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.shopping-list > li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.shopping-item {
  display: block;
  color: grey;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.shopping-item__checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Shopping List</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.2.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>

    <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
      <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
      <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
      <button type="submit">Add item</button>
    </form>

    <ul class="shopping-list">
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">oranges</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item shopping-item__checked">milk</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">bread</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Jacob, you're missing one simple thing, i.e., the buttons in your HTML code that you're appending. 

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('ul').append(`<li>Your button Text
</br>
<button>Check</button> 
<button>Delete</button></li>`)
});

I'd leave how to bind functions to the button upto your learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addItem()` method needs to include all of the HMTL to generate a new formatted item, not just the `<li>` element.

```
  function addItem(){
$('#js-shopping-list-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const textInput = $('#shopping-list-entry').val();
    $('ul').append('<li><span class="shopping-item">' + textInput + '</li></span> <div class="shopping-item-controls"> <button class="shopping-item-toggle">            <span class="button-label">check</span>          </button> <button class="shopping-item-delete"> <span class="button-label">delete</span> </button> </div>')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing code in jquery. replace the code and check

```
function addItem(){
    $('#js-shopping-list-form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const textInput = $('#shopping-list-entry').val();
        $('ul').append('<li><span class="shopping-item ">' + textInput +'</span><div class="shopping-item-controls"><button class="shopping-item-toggle"><span class="button-label">check</span></button><button class="shopping-item-delete"><span class="button-label">delete</span></button></div></li>')


    });
}
$(addItem);``
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example of you code. You have to add your `li` code to your jquery code.

```
      html = '<li>';
      html += '   <span class="shopping-item">' + textInput + '</span>';
      html += '   <div class="shopping-item-controls">';
      html += '     <button class="shopping-item-toggle">';
      html += '       <span class="button-label">check</span>';
      html += '     </button>';
      html += '     <button class="shopping-item-delete">';
      html += '       <span class="button-label">delete</span>';
      html += '     </button>';
      html += '   </div>';
      html += '</li>';
        $('ul').append(html)
```

Below is complete example of your code

```js
function addItem(){
    $('#js-shopping-list-form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const textInput = $('#shopping-list-entry').val();
        
      html = '<li>';
      html += '   <span class="shopping-item">' + textInput + '</span>';
      html += '   <div class="shopping-item-controls">';
      html += '     <button class="shopping-item-toggle">';
      html += '       <span class="button-label">check</span>';
      html += '     </button>';
      html += '     <button class="shopping-item-delete">';
      html += '       <span class="button-label">delete</span>';
      html += '     </button>';
      html += '   </div>';
      html += '</li>';
        $('ul').append(html)
    });
};
$(addItem);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button, input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#shopping-list-item {
  width: 250px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shopping-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.shopping-list > li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.shopping-item {
  display: block;
  color: grey;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.shopping-item__checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Shopping List</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.2.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>

    <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
      <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
      <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
      <button type="submit">Add item</button>
    </form>

    <ul class="shopping-list">
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">oranges</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item shopping-item__checked">milk</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">bread</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```